# Python Pandas dividing columns by column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two dataframes:

**df1**:

```
0   0.963996
1   0.313856
2   0.047924
3   0.034164
4   0.622996
```

and **df2**:

```
0   0.648803  0.042037  0.405195  0.194691
1   0.212756  0.481852  0.317786  0.631902
2   0.360745  0.940487  0.447977  0.398874
3   0.046590  0.291148  0.336938  0.119006
```

How do I divide every value in the first row of df2 by the value of the first row of df1, and so on for all rows?

I'm using

`df_divided = df_2.div(df_1.iloc[0], axis='column')`

right now but this seems to only divide every row of df2 by the value in the first row of df1

Comment: `df2 / df1.values`?

Comment: `df2 / df1.values` raises a `ValueError` here; `df2.values / df1.values` does the job though (as long as one doesn't care too much about ones labels and indices).